# How to write json mapping in java using elastic search RestHighLevelClient?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, resthighlevelclient

I have the below mapping and wondering how to write the same mapping in java using RestHighLevelClient

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "ecommerceData": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "comments": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "recommendationType": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to create(as its nested) is to put this mapping in `JSON format` in the file and then read it in string format(provided utility methods) and creates the mapping as shown below:

Other ways are mentioned in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html) official doc.

Create a file named `nested.mapping` and I will use the `nested` as an index name.

**Use following utility method to read the file and return it in `string` format**

```
public String getStringFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName); --> file name
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return result.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    }
```

**Resthighlevelclient code to create an index using above utility method**

```
 if (!isIndexExist(client, indexName)) {
                JsonUtil jsonUtil = new JsonUtil();
                String indexString = jsonUtil.getStringFromFile(indexName + ".mapping");
                CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
                request.source(indexString, XContentType.JSON);
                client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            }
```

Please see my java debugger screen-shot, which read this file properly in `JSON` format.

[image: debugger code image]

Finally, Elastic mapping API result, which shows index created successfully.

```
{
  "nested": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "events": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "ecommerceData": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "comments": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "recommendationType": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: which JsonUtil is being used here?